# Proof of number of non-isomorphic connected simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Want to prove that: 
the number of pairwise non-isomorphic connected simple graphs is greater than half of the number of non-isomorphic simple graphs with n vertices.
After observing it is true for small n, my attempt is to prove with induction.

It is obviously true for n=1. 
But I am having difficulty in finding the inductive steps. Could someone give some hint?

Update: Since a connected graph with n vertices must have at least n edges, so I consider C(n+1) > g(n)

Comment: I believe this conjecture fails for large n. The number of  nonisomorphic simple graphs on n vertices is given by [A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088). The number of nonisomorphic connected simple graphs on n vertices is given by [A001349](http://oeis.org/A001349).

Comment: @parafoo : Well it fails even for low n as well! for n=4, A000088(n) = 11 and A001349(n) = 6 - are A000088 and A001349 the right sequences?

Comment: I'm sorry that I just found a mistake in the question. It should be greater than half of the number of simple non-isomorphic graphs

Comment: @gilleain: I was assuming the poster meant the ceiling of half the number of connected nonisomorphic simple graphs as otherwise it does not even hold for n=1.

Comment: @Rachel Wu: What do $C(n+1)$ and $g(n)$ stand for?

Comment: C(n) denotes for the number of non-isomorphic connected graphs with n vertices and g(n) is the number of the non-isomorphic simple graph with n vertices